# Unity Shift+Space lags. Unity maximize view lags

Tags: unity-game-engine

When trying to maximize/restore the view by `Shift+Space` I experience some sort of lag.

When I hit `Shift+Space` twice it maximizes but doesn't restore view to the original size. I need to focus on a different element first or pan view or something. It is even worse with Game view, because there is no way to tell if you have "refocused" on something and the view doesn't maximize sometimes, when I click on it and press `Shift+Space`.

Is this a normal behavior?

Sometimes when exiting maximized view it turns completely black, like this: [black screen instead of Scene view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNrlT.png).

Do you know if it is possible to fix?

I am using Personal version of Unity 2021.3.9f1 (LTS) on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I have submitted a bug-report for a black Scene view because this is clearly not normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to solve the black screen but the game may have low frame rates because when you have the inspector open in unity it constantly updates which lags the game. Close the inspector or don't view it when you are running the game